# vba evaluate expression from string name

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I would kindly ask your support for the following issue:
I have a ws in EXCEL with a column of input (e.g. from L5 to L15) and in the last row of the column (L16) i put a generic formula that can be modified.

The VBA subroutine should read the formula in L16, traslate it in a vba expression and use it inside a `FOR-LOOP`.

This is an extract :

```
'get the formula 
formulaText = ws.Range("L" & ultimaRigaQuote + 1).formula
'manage the formula
formulaText = Mid(formulaText, 2)
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "SUM", "Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "IF", "IIf")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "SIN", "Application.WorksheetFunction.Sin")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "COS", "Application.WorksheetFunction.Cos")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "TAN", "Tan")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "RADIANS","Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "SQRT", "Application.WorksheetFunction.Sqr")
formulaText = Replace(formulaText, "PI()", "Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi")

For i = 1 To nSimulazioni
'assign the value to the input
For j = 5 To ultimaRigaQuote
Z_Var(j - 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, MediaVal(j - 
5), DevStd(j - 5))
MediaCalc(j - 5) = Z_Var(j - 5)
Next j
'use them in the expression
risultato(i) = Evaluate(formulaText)
Next i
```

all works fine but the problem is in the `"Evaluate(formulaText)"`. If I put directly the content of the string `"formulaText"` into the brackets, the script works but if i put the name of the string `(formulaText)` it does not work

for example the string is MediaCalc(0)+MediaCalc(1)-2*MediaCalc(2)/MediaCalc(3)+TAN(RADIANS(MediaCalc(4)))+MediaCalc(5)+MediaCalc(6)

if I write in the script
risultato(i) = Evaluate(formulaText) --> does not work

if I write in the script
risultato(i) = Evaluate(MediaCalc(0)+MediaCalc(1)-2*MediaCalc(2)/MediaCalc(3)+TAN(RADIANS(MediaCalc(4)))+MediaCalc(5)+MediaCalc(6)) --> it works

Now i wnat to understand why the system does not works with the title of the string but it works with the content of the string

please can you help me?

tnx
Ema

fix the problem with the `evaluate function`

Comment: Describe what you want to achieve and show what your data looks like, because your code looks weird.

Comment: thanks 
the script should create a montecarlo analysis from a stackup analysis present on the excel ws
sorry i missed a part of code:

For j = 5 To ultimaRigaQuote
    
      Z_Var(j - 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, MediaVal(j - 5), DevStd(j - 5))
      MediaCalc(j - 5) = Z_Var(j - 5)
  Next j

at now the content of "formulaText" is "=MediaCalc(0)+MediaCalc(1)-2*MediaCalc(2)/MediaCalc(3)+TAN(RADIANS(MediaCalc(4)))+MediaCalc(5)+MediaCalc(6)"

Comment: Could you edit your question and add extra info to it.  The edit button is at the bottom of the question.  If you need to include data it's best to include it as a [formatted table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) that can be copied/pasted.

Comment: Hello Darren tnx for the suggeestion, from my tests the point of the issue is focused about the correct syntax of the function evaluate

Comment: `Evaluate` requires Excel syntax, so if your `MediaCalc` is an array, it should be something like that: `Evaluate("=" & MediaCalc(0)+MediaCalc(1)-2*MediaCalc(2)/MediaCalc(3) & "+TAN(RADIANS(" & MediaCalc(4) & "))+" & MediaCalc(5)+MediaCalc(6))` This is an idea. Not tested.

Comment: Tnx MGonet the problem is that i would to change the formula everytimes so i have to use the name of the string and not the string itself. As I already wrote, the function:  Evaluate(MediaCalc(0)+MediaCalc(1)-2*MediaCalc(2)/MediaCalc(3)+TAN(RADIANS(MediaCalc(4)))+MediaCalc(5)+MediaCalc(6)) 
works well
so the problem is only when i put in the evaluate brackets the name of the string and not the string

Comment: It cannot work well because only `Tan` is available in VBA and `RADIANS` is from Excel, so it should be `Worksheetfunction.Radians`. However if ypou

Comment: yes correct, I didi the modification but it does not work yet

Comment: However if you can calculate an argument in VBA, then `Evaluate` is needless. You need `Evaluate` if your formula is in text form. If an argument of `Evaluate` is a text you should use an Excel syntax and that's all (assuming you use point, not comma, as decimal separator). It doesn't matter if you use `a = Evaluate("some formula as text")` or `Dim myformula As String: myformula="some formula as text": a = Evaluate(myformula)`

Comment: Your next comment: so what works and what doesn't?

Comment: In Excel do you use decimal point or comma as decimal separator?

Comment: exact that's the point! In parallel i brought ahead some tests and the problems were the commas. Now i went back to write to you and I found your comment. Tns a lot MGonet for your precious suppport. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Analyse the code below. The `Str` function is necessary if you use comma as decimal separator (in Excel). If you use decimal point you can omit `Str`.

```
Sub Test_Evaluate()
    Dim MediaCalc
    MediaCalc = Array(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 12.5, 1.5, 1.8)
    Dim res As Double, ftext As String
    ftext = Str(MediaCalc(0) + MediaCalc(1) - 2 * MediaCalc(2) / MediaCalc(3)) & "+TAN(RADIANS(" & Str(MediaCalc(4)) & "))+" & Str(MediaCalc(5) + MediaCalc(6))
    Debug.Print ftext
    res = Evaluate(ftext)
    Debug.Print res
    res = Evaluate(MediaCalc(0) + MediaCalc(1) - 2 * MediaCalc(2) / MediaCalc(3) + Tan(WorksheetFunction.Radians(MediaCalc(4))) + MediaCalc(5) + MediaCalc(6))
    Debug.Print res
End Sub
```